# Append a None to List in Robot Framework

Tags: list, null, append, robotframework

my current keyword is checking for the existence of an element and if it exists, appending content found to list:

```
${present}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element    ${Locator}
Run Keyword If Present    ${present}=    Get Text    ${Locator}
```

However, where the item is not present, I'd like to append a None or Null entry to the list I am building of the items found (or not found) at that element.

How can this be achieved, please?